# How can I add a LXDE shortcut to launch an application?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

In KDE's menu editor, one can click on the "Advanced tab" and then set a keyboard shortcut to launch an application.

How can I emulate that functionality in LXDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Openbox#Create_custom_keyboard_shortcuts

It might not emulate the functionality completely, but it can run commands via keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Link is down. :(

Answer (score 5):

More documentation is here:

- http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings (from Christoffer's link)
- http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions -- very nice list of actions

on OpenSuSE, one edits the appropriate file in ~/.config/openbox, namely `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`, and can update the running configuration with `openbox-lxde --reconfigure`

I added the following in the `<keyboard>` section,

```
<!-- Maximize commands -->
<keybind key="W-Up">
    <action name="ToggleMaximizeFull" />
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-S-Up">
    <action name="ToggleMaximizeVert" />
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-S-Down">
    <action name="ToggleMaximizeHorz" />
</keybind>

<!-- application execute commands -->
<keybind key="W-f">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>chromium</command>
    </action>
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-t">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>lxterminal</command>
    </action>
</keybind>

<!-- logout -->
<keybind key="C-A-S-Delete">
    <action name="Exit">
        <prompt>no</prompt>
    </action>
</keybind>

<!-- window movement -->
<keybind key="W-A-Up">
    <action name="MoveToEdgeNorth"/>
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-A-Down">
    <action name="MoveToEdgeSouth"/>
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-A-Left">
    <action name="MoveToEdgeWest"/>
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-A-Right">
    <action name="MoveToEdgeEast"/>
</keybind>
```